# Web2py, how I do a select with inner join in a list: reference

Tags: python-3.x, web2py

I am trying do a select and do a inner join with list:reference with table Kits and Estoque but its returning nothing. If I remove the join the select works, but in the view it doesn't show one TR with more than one product of a kit, create one TR for which produto of a kit, someone can help me? Here is my code

db.py

```
db.define_table('TipoUnidade',
                Field('TipoUnidadeDescricao'),
                format='%(TipoUnidadeDescricao)s'
                )

db.define_table('Produto',
                Field('ID_TipoUnidade', 'reference TipoUnidade', requires=IS_IN_SET(['Unidade', 'Gramas'])),
                Field('CodigoBarras', type='integer'),
                Field('CodigoCacauShow', type='integer'),
                Field('CustoUnitario', type='double'),
                Field('QuantidadeMinima', type='double'),
                Field('ProdutoDescricao', type='string', label='Produto'),
                format='%(ProdutoDescricao)s'
                )

db.define_table('EntradaProdutoEstoque',
                Field('ID_Produto', 'reference Produto'),
                Field('Validade', type='date'),
                Field('Data', type='date'),
                Field('Quantidade', type='double'),
                Field('Lote'),
                format='%(Lote)s' + ' - ' + '%(ID_Produto)s'
                )

db.define_table('Estoque',
                Field('ID_Produto', 'reference Produto'),
                Field('Ativo', type='boolean', default=True),
                Field('Validade', type='date'),
                Field('Quantidade', type='double'),
                Field('DataDesativacao',type='date'),
                Field('Lote')
                )



db.define_table('Kits',
                Field('Nome'),
                Field('ID_Estoque', 'list:reference Estoque'),
                Field('QuantidadeProdutos', type='list:integer',label="Quantidade de Produtos"),
                Field('QuantidadeKits', type='integer', label="Quantidade de Kits")
                )

db.define_table('SaidaProdutoEstoque',
                Field('ID_Estoque', 'reference Estoque'),
                #Field('CustoTotal', type='double'),
                Field('Data', type='date'),
                Field('Quantidade', type='double'),
                )
```

default.py

```
def kits():
    

    Kits = db().select(db.Produto.ProdutoDescricao,db.Estoque.Lote, db.Kits.QuantidadeKits, db.Kits.Nome,
                       join=(db.Estoque.on(db.Kits.ID_Estoque == db.Estoque.id),
                             db.Produto.on(db.Estoque.ID_Produto == db.Produto.id)))

    return dict(tabelaKits=Kits)
```

kits.html

```
{{for produto in tabelaKits:}}
          <tr>
              <td id="DescProd">{{=produto.Kits.Nome}}</td>
              <td id="DescProd">{{=produto.Produto.ProdutoDescricao}} - {{=produto.Estoque.Lote}}</td>
              <td id="DescProd">{{=produto.QuantidadeKits}}</td>
              <th id="DescCamp"><button>VISUALIZAR</button></th>
          </tr>
      {{pass}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.Estoque.on(db.Kits.ID_Estoque == db.Estoque.id)
```

Above, keep in mind that `db.Kits.ID_Estoque` stores a list of ID's, not a single ID, so you cannot simply equate it with `db.Estoque.id`. Instead, as noted in the [documentation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#list-type-and-contains), you can use the `.contains` method with `list:`-type fields:

```
db.Estoque.on(db.Kits.ID_Estoque.contains(db.Estoque.id))
```

Note, though, that the above is not an efficient query, as it translate to a `LIKE` search inside a string field. If you run into performance issues, you might consider switching to a more standard many-to-many design with a join table.

Comment: It's worked, but in my table show only one product even I registering more than 1 product in a kit

Comment: Please update your question to show (a) a few related rows from each of the tables (at least the relevant fields from each table), (b) the exact query and grid code you are using, and (c) the output you are getting.